# Can't get this shadertoy shader to work in GLSL with OpenGL 2.0

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

The shader I've converted below throws the following errors in LibGDX with Opengl 2.0:

```
ERROR: 0:08: '<<' does not operate on 'int' and 'int'
ERROR: 0:23: No matching function for call to mod(int, int)
ERROR: 0:24: Invalid call of undeclared identifier 'textureLod'
```

Obviously I commented out and replaced certain parts to see the errors further down but the errors should be all the problems it has.

```
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform vec2 resolution;

const int samples = 35, LOD = 2, sLOD = 1 << LOD;//error here
const float sigma = float(samples) * .25;

float gaussian(vec2 i) {
    return exp( -.5* dot(i/=sigma,i) ) / ( 6.28 * sigma*sigma );
}

void main() {
    vec2 u = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution.xy;

    vec4 o = vec4(0);  
    int s = samples/sLOD;
    vec2 scale = vec2(1,1);

    for ( int i = 0; i < s*s; i++ ) {
        vec2 d = vec2(mod(i,s), i/s)*float(sLOD) - float(samples)/2.;//error here
        o += gaussian(d) * textureLod( u_texture, u + scale * d , float(LOD) );//error here
    }

    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);//simply outputs default image at the moment since the above has errors
}
```

There's not really any easy or good way to use anything higher than opengl 2.0 in LibGDX but I'm wondering if there's a workaround or alternative to any of these commands. Not sure particularly why `mod` doesn't work - it only works with `float` ?

Comment: For [`textureLod`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/textureLod.xhtml) you have to use at least [OpenGL Shading Language 1.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) (OpenGL 3.0)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes I know these errors are all due to using OpenGL 2, I was just wondering if there were any workarounds to get this to work without those functions.